# Webhooks with Amazon EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, webhooks

I use EC2 instances to host my sites, and I'm currently (attempting) to set up an autodeployment pipeline using the [webhook](https://github.com/adnanh/webhook) library and Github Webhooks. I'm following the guides on webhook's repo as well as [this blogpost](https://medium.com/better-programming/how-to-automatically-deploy-from-github-to-server-using-webhook-79f837dcc4f4) (which I understand is for use with digital ocean stuff, but I figure the same stuff generally applies).

I am able to set up the proper configuration files on my EC2 instance – I had to specify that the webhook library serve/consume content from the instance's *private* IP address, which is (based on my understanding) NATed to automatically by the elastic IP assigned to the instance. Here is my current `hooks.json` file:

```
[{
    "id": "autodeploy",
    "execute-command": "/home/ubuntu/webhooks/autodeploy/deploy.sh",
    "command-working-directory": "/home/ubuntu/site",
    "response-message": "Executing deploy script..."
}]
```

According to the documentation, this tells webhook that, when a certain endpoint is hit with a `GET`/`POST` request, the script at the path denoted by `execute-command` will be executed. To actually start the server to receive these `GET`/`POST` requests, I run the below command (and get the below output):

```
ubuntu@ip-xxx-xx-xx-xxx:~/webhooks$ webhook -hooks hooks.json -ip "xxx-xx-xx-xxx" -verbose
[webhook] 2019/12/22 08:30:48 version 2.5.0 starting
[webhook] 2019/12/22 08:30:48 setting up os signal watcher
[webhook] 2019/12/22 08:30:48 attempting to load hooks from hooks.json
[webhook] 2019/12/22 08:30:48 found 1 hook(s) in file
[webhook] 2019/12/22 08:30:48   loaded: autodeploy
[webhook] 2019/12/22 08:30:48 serving hooks on http://xxx-xx-xx-xxx:9000/hooks/{id}
[webhook] 2019/12/22 08:30:48 os signal watcher ready
```

Now, `xxx-xx-xx-xxx` is the private IP to which the webhook server is bound. I've associated an elastic/public IP with the EC2 instance, but whenever I send a `GET` request to `http://XX-XXX-XXX-XX:9000/hooks/autodeploy`, I get no response back (where `XX-XXX-XXX-XX` denotes the instance's elastic IP); furthermore, when I try to use Github Webhooks to send a `POST` request to this endpoint automatically, I get a "could not deliver to endpoint" error.

Any ideas as to what this could be?

Comment: can you share a detailed guid on how to set this up

Answer (score 5):

Okay so I'm totally an idiot and didn't create a security rule that allowed my instance to be accessed at port 9000. Total dummy move.

(To set up this rule, go to Network and Security > Security Groups and add a new security group that opens port 9000 for TCP access, then associate this rule to the EC2 instance you're working with.)

Comment: Wanted to avoid opening it up to the world, but it makes sense.